Verify the formula for the the 3-simplex
One book I'm reading defines the regular 3-dimensional simplex as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as follows:
$$
\{\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4: x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1, x_i\ge 0, i=\{ 1, 2, 3 ,4\}\}.
$$
Update: My understanding is that all faces of a regular 3-dimensional simplex are equilateral triangles.
I'm trying to verify this formula by checking if all $\mathbf{x}$ satisfying the equation above eventually actually form a tetrahedron. However, I'm having trouble with the forth dimension.
For the formula for the regular 2-simplex, that is:
$$
\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3: x_1+x_2+x_3=1, x_i\ge 0, i=\{ 1, 2, 3\}\}.
$$
Then it's easy to verify since the intersections of the half-space $x\ge 0$ and the hyperplane $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$ for example can be identified in the graph.

And the way I reconstruct the 2-simplex from the formula is by rewriting the equation as $x_1+x_2=1-x_3$ then varying $x_3$ in the range $[0, 1]$ and finally keeping track of $\mathbf{x}$. You can see the animation of this approach here, the locus of $\mathbf{x}$ actually forms the 2-simplex.
For the 3-simplex using the same approach, I didn't get the desired 3-D solid for the tetrahedron. This is because the 3-D coordinate system fails to take into account the forth dimension. The animation can be found here.
So is there any way to verify the formula for 3-simplex is actually correct?

In what sense do you want to verify its correctness? Do you want a proof of the claim that the polytope defined by the formula is a $3$-dimensional solid with $4$ faces, for example?

Yes it's true and more importantly I want to show that the four faces are equilateral triangles.

We can argue inductively. If $S = \{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^4 : \mathbf x \ge 0 \text{ and } x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1\}$ is the set we're trying to understand, then it has four faces given by the inequalities $x_1 \ge0$, $x_2\ge0$, $x_3 \ge 0$, and $x_4 \ge 0$. A point lies on one of these faces if the two sides of the inequality are equal.
For example, one face is the face where $x_4=0$. This gives us the set $$\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^4 : x_4=0 \text{ and }x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0\text{ and }x_1+x_2+x_3=1\}.$$ This is a subset of the hyperplane $x_4=0$, and in that hyperplane, what we're looking at is exactly the regular $2$-simplex.
Similarly, if we look at the face where $x_1=0$, then we'll be looking at  a regular $2$-simplex, just in different variables: in the variables $x_2, x_3, x_4$. (The two faces are congruent, because an isometry that swaps variables around turns one into the other.) Similarly, the $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$ faces are congruent to the other two.
So we've shown that the regular $3$-simplex $S$ has four faces, which are congruent regular $2$-simplices, and assuming we already know that a regular $2$-simplex is an equilateral triangle, we learn that $S$ is a regular tetrahedron.

one question: How do we that by setting $x_1=0$ for example, we will get the equation of the face of the the 3-simplex? My observation is that by setting each coordinate of $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4$ equal to $0$, we will receive points in 3 different 3-D coordinate systems respectively, which is similar to the case in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where we set each coordinate of $\mathbf{x}$ equal to $0$, we will get points in 3 different planes respectively. However, concluding that each case makes up 1 face in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is not very easy to see for me.

We know we've got a face because we got a $2$-dimensional result, and we started with a $3$-dimensional polytope. (We started with a $3$-dimensional polytope because it is contained in an affine hyperplane $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1$ in $\mathbb R^4$.)

I'd like to add another analytic proof on top of @Misha Lavrov's above. (IMHO, this proof is a bit more intuitive in one part.)
The first step is to argue that the points generated by the the formula for the regular 3-simplex can be accommodated in a 3-D coordinate system. We do this by choosing an appropriate origin and a set of (three) bases.
Let the origin of this new coordinate system be $O_1=(0, 0, 0, 1)$ and 3 basis vectors with reference to this origin are: $\overrightarrow{i}_1=(1, 0, 0, -1)$,  $\overrightarrow{j}_1=(0, 1, 0, -1)$ and  $\overrightarrow{k}_1=(0, 0, 1, -1)$ whose positions with reference to the standard origin $O(0, 0, 0, 0)$ will be $(1, 0, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1, 0)$ respectively. It's easy to verify that those vectors are linear independent.
Now, any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying the formula for the regular 3-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, x_3, 1-x_1-x_2-x_3)$.
And so in this system we can represent $\mathbf{x}$ as $\mathbf{x}=x_1\overrightarrow{i}_1+x_2\overrightarrow{j}_1+x_3\overrightarrow{k}_1$ (note that the origin of the new 3-D coordinate system is $O_1(0, 0, 0, 1)$). In other words, we have shown that all points satisfying the formula can be represented in a vector space of dimension 3.
The second step is to show that each edge of the 3-simplex is of the same length. This can be done by induction similar to @Misha Lavrov's answer. Moreover, we can verify that this common length equals $\sqrt{2}$.
One point that I take for granted in this proof is the fact that the formula for the set $\{\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x_1+x_2+x_3\le 1, x_i\ge 0\text{ for }i=1, 2, 3\}$ forms a 3-D solid.
